# Безопасность php кода

Tags: книги, безопасность, php

Здравствуйте! Посоветуйте книгу или учебник или цикл статей, которые надо прочитать и освоить, чтобы проект был сделан максимально безопасным.

Чтобы там были описаны основные уязвимости и как их избежать.
Подробное руководство настройки и оптимизации php.ini
Советы и рекомендации.

Comment: я б почитал.

Comment: Прочитайте документацию по php.ini, не доверяйте пользователю. Думаю этого хватит.

Comment: Не храните md5 хэш паролей без соли, в .htacess смените расширение скриптов на .html и выключите expose_php в php.ini, отключите сообщения об ошибках.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю такой книги нет,но вы можете почитать про все [уязвимости](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246978/Threat-Classification).

Answer (score 4):

Почему все думают, что защита сайта это только php скрипты, проверки вводимых данных?

Сервер тоже должен быть настроен правильно, со своими политиками безопасности, только с нужными модулями Apache к примеру, с доступам только по нужным портам и т.д. Доступ к Mysql серверу если таковой используется, PostgreSql тоже самое

Защита сайта это целый комплект мер, для предотвращения взлома, как сайта, так и сервера в целом.

Читать нужно про все, в нете информации много, фильтровать её достаточно просто, по первым фразам статьи можно понять, нужна ли она либо сразу закрыть её.

Многие книги устарели, в связи с тем что писались немного под другие вещи, под те которые во многом уже и не используются. Т.к. IT сфера каждый месяц идет вперед и расширяется в немыслимой прогрессии, за всем и не уследить.

Answer (score 2):

- [Как я фильтрую переменные в PHP](habrahabr.ru/post/146491/);
- [Защита от SQL-инъекций в PHP и MySQL](habrahabr.ru/post/148701/).

Для начала хватит. А вообще попробуй написать скрипт сам и прогнать через xspider, поможет посмотреть на совершенные ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Начал читать  книгу "Михаил_Фленов-PHP_глазами_хакера".
Есть хорошая информация по защите,но жаль мало практических примеров